# Migrar IIS de un Windows Server 2000 a un Windows 10

Tags: php, webservice, windows, aplicación-web, iis

¿Es posible migrar todo el contenido del IIS que hay en un windows server 2000 (creo que la versión del iis es la 5.0) a un windows 10?

El objetivo es pasar todo ese contenido a un sistema más actual. Supongo que en el equipo antiguo, tendría problemas de compatibilidad, por ejemplo, con versiones actuales de php, ¿no?.

---

(Editado)

He estado investigando, y la versión mínima que necesito para que mi aplicación web funcione correctamente es la 5. Al parecer, IIS 7 acepta esa versión. Lo que ocurre es que en windows server 2000 esta la versión 5.0, y creo que no se puede actualizar. Única solución que veo, migrarlo todo a un windows 10 con iis instalado.

¿Alguien puede arrojar luz al asunto?
¿Muevo la pregunta a otro tipo de foro?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Pelayo. ¿Lo has intentado? Has visto errores de compatiblilidad? Comprueba las versiones como dices y mira las documentaciones oficiales por si hay cambios *letales* para tu aplicacion y que deban ser modificados o actualizados. Un saludo

Comment: Que versión de php tienes pensado instalar en el nuevo windows10? Seguramente en el equipo con WindowsServer 2000 tengas aplicaciones con php4 o incluso php3 que seguramente no sean compatibles con php7 en el caso de instalar esa versión en el windows10. Si instalas php5 en el windows10... otra cosa es

Comment: @ilernet pues mirando mi código php creo que con la última versión de php 5 todo iría correcto. Entiendo que en el windows server 2000 (por su antigüedad) no puedo actualizar a dicha versión no? o si? Perdón por mi ignorancia...

Comment: Aqui te dejo un link , en principio a la 5.3.0 parece que si que puedes actualizar   https://blog.mehl-web.de/post/2009/12/12/How-To-Install-IIS-7-PHP5-and-MySQL-51-on-Windows-Server-2008.aspx

Comment: @ilernet parece que es con la versión IIS 7.0, creo que la que viene en mi windows server es la 5.0, habría que hacer algún tipo de actualización, no?